# Как подписаться на событие из динамически подключенной библиотеки?

Tags: c#, события, делегаты

Есть библиотека, в классе которой объявлено событие и делегат:

```
namespace ChessLib
{
    public class ChessField
    {
        public delegate void Write(IntermedOption i);
        public event Write ArrWrite;
```

В новом проекте подключаю динамически данную библиотеку. С методами библиотеки работать получается, но возникла проблема с подпиской на событие. Подскажите как это сделать:

```
static void Main()
{
      Assembly a = Assembly.Load("ChessLib");

      Type chessField = a.GetType("ChessLib.ChessField");
      Type intermedOption = a.GetType("ChessLib.IntermedOption");
      Console.WriteLine("Введите размерность поля");
      int sizeOfField = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      object chessObj = Activator.CreateInstance(chessField, new object[] { sizeOfField, true });
      //!subscription on the event here.!
```

У меня в классе program 2 метода обработчика, и мне надо на подписаться на 2 разных обработчика.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023129/subscribe-to-an-event-of-a-loaded-assembly

Comment: @ГеннадийП можете перевести на русский и запостить как ответ.

Comment: Там нормального ответа не дано.

Comment: То что вам тот ответ не понятен, не значит что он не нормальный. Я например не знал ответа, но посмотрев там всё стало понятно.

Comment: @aepot ответ неполный , что за второй параметр у AddEventHandler. У меня в новом проекте 2 метода обработчика, которые идентичны сигнатуре делегата события в библиотеке. Как мне это сделать ?

Comment: _что за второй параметр у AddEventHandler_: первый - экземпляр класса, где находится метод, второй - делегат, указывающий на обработчик. _2 метода обработчика_: значит надо 2 раза вызвать `AddEventHandler`. Там в ответе ссылки на [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.eventinfo.addeventhandler?view=net-5.0). Вы их не заметили?

Comment: `У меня в новом проекте 2 метода обработчика` Через [GetEvent](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.getevent) берете нужное событие, и подключаете сколько нужно обработчиков через AddEventHandler. Ну это же так сложно почитать пару страниц документации, где даже все с примерами расписано.